# Show both question user owner and last-activity user on question listing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, question-lists

In the questions list it shows the name of the last active user on that question.

Wouldn't it be nice to show both user that asked (fixed) and last-activity below?

Example here:

[image]

Comment: +1  It took me about 3 minutes to understand your question, but it's a great idea.

Comment: @Gabe hahaha sorry, my english is very poor!!

Comment: I like this. I don't know how many times people have told me about a question I supposedly asked, when I had just edited / answered it and they saw only my name under the question in the listing. This part of the UI has always bugged me.

Comment: @BradLarson I agree. I think it can be useful